# Remove sublist from multidimensional list based on a condition [PYTHON]

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists that looks thus:

```
[['cat', 'dog', 'fish'], ['panda', 'bear', 'foo']]
```

How can I remove the sublist which contains a particular string, for example, in this case, the list that contains 'foo'?

Comment: `[sub for sub in lst if 'foo' not in sub]` That's all

Comment: think of it like building a sublist with the items you want to keep instead of trying to figure out what to remove.